# cmake produces error: "conflicting types for ‘stat64’"

Tags: c, cmake

I am in the process of converting my gmake build to cmake builds. The application builds fine with gmake, but I get the errors below when I use cmake.
Below are the gmake and cmake files.

## parent Makefile

```
CC      := gcc
CFLAGS  := -g -w -m32
INC_DIR := ../includes
OBJ_DIR := ../objects
BIN_DIR := ../bin
```

## child Makefile

```
include ../../Makefile

SHR_FX := ../$(OBJ_DIR)/shrfx.o
SHRXML := ../$(OBJ_DIR)/shrxml.o
TMP_BIN_DIR = ../$(BIN_DIR)
TMP_INC_DIR = ../$(INC_DIR)

EXECUTABLES := common flogmon
all: $(EXECUTABLES)

%: %.c OAhelper.c OAhelper.h $(SHR_FX) $(TMP_INC_DIR)
    @-rm -f $@   ## QUIET (@). CONTINUE IF FILE NOT FOUND (-)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I $(TMP_INC_DIR) $(LDLIBPATHFLAGS) -o $@ $@.c  OAhelper.c $(SHR_FX) 
    @-chmod 0775 $@   #SH(@),CONT(-). Allow others to do it.
    mv $@ $(TMP_BIN_DIR)
```

## parent CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project(program)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
set (EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "/home/user/workspace/program")

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -g -w -m32")

add_subdirectory(opaid/opaid_helper)
```

## child CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)

#Bring the headers
include_directories(../../includes)

set (PROJ_LIST "common;flogmon")

message ( STATUS "CFLAGS : " ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS})
foreach (PROJ ${PROJ_LIST})
    project(${PROJ})
    SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-rpath=${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}:${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}../RSA/cryptocme3001/library/lib")
    add_executable(${PROJ} ${PROJ}.c OAhelper.c )
    target_link_libraries(${PROJ} LINK_PUBLIC shrfx)
    install(TARGETS ${PROJ} DESTINATION ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH})
endforeach()
```

## Error

```
Building C object /CMakeFiles/common.dir/common.c.o
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:375:0,
    from /usr/include/sys/poll.h:22,
    from /usr/include/poll.h:1,
    from /home/user/workspace/program/src/common.c:26:
/usr/include/sys/stat.h:503:1: error: conflicting types for ‘stat64’
__NTH (stat64 (const char *__path, struct stat64 *__statbuf))
^
In file included from
/home/user/workspace/program/src/../../includes/fxgen.h:205:0,
    from /home/user/workspace/program/src/../../includes/fx.h:286, 
    from /home/user/workspace/program/src/common.c:39:
/usr/include/sys/stat.h:229:12: note: previous declaration of ‘stat64’
was here extern int stat64 (const char *__restrict __file,
```

If I look in /usr/include/sys/stat.h...

```
503
# if defined __USE_LARGEFILE64 \
  && (! defined __USE_FILE_OFFSET64 \
      || (defined __REDIRECT_NTH && defined __OPTIMIZE__))
__extern_inline int
__NTH (stat64 (const char *__path, struct stat64 *__statbuf))
{
  return __xstat64 (_STAT_VER, __path, __statbuf);
}

229
#ifdef __USE_LARGEFILE64
extern int stat64 (const char *__restrict __file,
           struct stat64 *__restrict __buf) __THROW __nonnull ((1, 2));
extern int fstat64 (int __fd, struct stat64 *__buf) __THROW __nonnull ((2));
#endif
```

Comment: Run `make VERBOSE=1` and check difference between command line in gmake invocation.

Comment: It looks as though you're missing the last part of the last error line.  However, it probably isn't a big issue — it is likely `struct stat64 *__statbuf);` or something equivalent that is missing.  You're likely to have to track down what `common.c` or the `fx.h` and `fxgen.h` headers are doing to make two incompatible declarations of `stat64()` visible.  The trouble could be in another header previously included by `common.c`, but I'd start with those.  (Using `gcc -H` lists all the included files as they're included — it may help too.)

Comment: Note that CMake is not an analog of [g]make; it is more along the lines of the Autotools.  Indeed, chances are excellent that the makefiles generated for you by CMake will be processed by gmake (== GNU make) on all the platforms where it handles your old makefiles.

Comment: Anyway, as you analyze the difference in build commands, look especially for differences in command-line macro definitions.  Look also for (probably conditional) macro definitions between lines 26 and 39 of your `common.c`.  Overall, all macro definitions that may affect header file interpretation should be made before any header inclusions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions,using VERBOSE=1: cmake has -03 -DNDEBUG which gmake does not.  How can I get rid of those complier flags in cmake?

Comment: These flags are originated from *CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE* variable, which usage is triggered by setting "Release" build type. You may assign other value to the variable (after the `project()` call), or use other build type.

Comment: @Tsyvarev  I assume that is probably not causing my problem. right?

Comment: I don't know what causes your problem. It looks like some inconsistency with `sys/stat.h` system header, and it is very OS-specific. You may try to google for error message (`conflicting types for ‘stat64’`).

Comment: I have been slowly rebuilding the make command from the command line and it fails when "-O3" is added.  any suggestions on how to remove this?  I searched on line and it was suggested I added "-O0" to my flags, but "-O3" STILL gets added and it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my CMAKEList.txt solved the problem:

STRING(REPLACE "-O3" "-O0" CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE})